# Create XML file in SQL with table data displayed by field instead of by record

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, xml, oracle

I want to create an XML file from a table pulling all the records and basically exporting it in an XML file. The catch is, it needs to be formatted specifically so that the records are broken up by field. So for example, all the IDs, then all the customer names, then the address, etc. Sounds weird but this is what I need. For example, in the record set:

```
ID Fname Lname
1  Joe   Shmoe
2  kyle  Shoobert
3  Kernel Sanders
4  Bad    Joke
```

It would look like this in XML:

```
<root>
    <IDs>
      <key>1</key>
      <key>2</key>
      <key>3</key>
      <key>4</key>
    </IDs>
    <fnames>
      <key>Joe</key>
      <key>Kyle</key>
      <key>Kernel</key>
      <key>bad</key>
    </names>
    <lname>
      <key>Schmoe</key>
      <key>Shoobert</key>
      <key>Sanders</key>
      <key>Joke</key>
    </lname>
</root>
```

Then after that, Say they have a GPA field, I want the xml to have another field set that calculates the averages or their fields, so each record would have a GPA1, GPA2, etc and average them.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Not sure how to be more clear on the question, but seeing as how it was answered I apologize for those who were unable to understand my wording. I will work on it in the future.

Comment: Is there a technical limitation why applying an XSLT to the output from SQL Server is out of the question?

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle : Different

Comment: To clearify as issue was on hold, I simply needed a way to export records in such a way that allowed me to format them into a finished XML document. Jaaz Cole answered the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit involved, but basically, store your template in a temp table, and use it un successive updates in a cursor on the student's ID. It should be relatively fast, even for a cursor, but won't be nearly as fast as if the data was arranged to be exported that way in the first place. Kind of tricky to get the right pivot, but hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, fname VARCHAR(20), lname VARCHAR(20), GPA1 numeric(4,2), GPA2 numeric(4,2), GPAAvg AS (GPA1 + GPA2)/2.0)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (1, 'Joe', 'Schmoe', 3.45, 3.6)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (2, 'Kyle', 'Shoobert', 2.7, 4.0)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (3, 'Kernel', 'Sanders', 3.2, 3.8)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (4, 'bad', 'Joke', 3.99, 3.11)

declare @result table (r xml)
insert into @result values (N'<root>
    <IDs/>
    <fnames/>
    <lnames/>
    <GPAs1/>
    <GPAs2/>
    <Avgs/>
</root>')

declare @ID int
declare GradeCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT ID
    FROM @temp
    ORDER BY ID

open GradeCursor
fetch next from GradeCursor into @ID

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    UPDATE RES
        SET R.modify('insert element ID {sql:column("ID")} as last into (/root/IDs)[1]')
        FROM @result RES
            inner join @temp t on t.ID = @ID
    UPDATE RES
        SET R.modify('insert element fname {sql:column("fname")} as last into (/root/fnames)[1]')
        FROM @result RES
            inner join @temp t on t.ID = @ID
    UPDATE RES
        SET R.modify('insert element lname {sql:column("lname")} as last into (/root/lnames)[1]')
        FROM @result RES
            inner join @temp t on t.ID = @ID
    UPDATE RES
        SET R.modify('insert element GPA1 {sql:column("GPA1")} as last into (/root/GPAs1)[1]')
        FROM @result RES
            inner join @temp t on t.ID = @ID
    UPDATE RES
        SET R.modify('insert element GPA2 {sql:column("GPA2")} as last into (/root/GPAs2)[1]')
        FROM @result RES
            inner join @temp t on t.ID = @ID
    UPDATE RES
        SET R.modify('insert element Avg {sql:column("GPAAvg")} as last into (/root/Avgs)[1]')
        FROM @result RES
            inner join @temp t on t.ID = @ID
    fetch next from GradeCursor into @ID
end
close GradeCursor
deallocate GradeCursor

select * FROM @result
```

Comment: Speed is not an issue, Luckily the records are already in a table to use so the temp table isn't necessary. This is great and put me on the right track. Thanks alot for your code.